# Can maximal filters of nowhere meager subsets of Cantor space be countably complete?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $X$ denote Cantor space. A subset $A\subseteq X$ is *nowhere meager* if for every non-empty open $U\subseteq X$, we have $A\cap U$ non-meager. We call $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ a *maximal nowhere-meager filter* if $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter of nowhere meager subsets of $X$ which is maximal with this property.

Is it consistent that there exists a countably complete maximal nowhere-meager filter? If so, what is the consistency strength of the existence of such an object?

Comment: I wonder whether one can hope to make an instance of this by performing a length $\omega_1$ forcing iteration (or longer, but uncountable cofinality), and defining the filter by reference to certain comeager sets appearing along the way? The idea would be that any countably many sets in the filter would have all appeared at some stage of the iteration, and so that instance would already have been handled along the way by genericity.

Comment: One thing I can mention is that such an object is not possible under CH. The argument for this is a bit circuitous. So I’m wondering about constructions either assuming MA, or if some large cardinal strength is needed, assuming that the continuum is a measurable.

Comment: Ah, I meant that the continuum admits a countably complete ultrafilter.

Comment: Can you easily describe a set that is nowhere meager but not comeager?

Comment: (The continuum cannot admit a countably complete nonprincipal ultrafilter. Do you intend to say that the continuum is real-valued measurable?)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Easliy describable? Probably not: if it has the Baire property then it is co-meager. Something like a Bernstein set is nowhere meager by not co-meager.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I meant real-valued measurable; really anything with the consistency strength of a measurable here.